# Providing custom class as a DefaultValueSerDes giving an error

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

We have made our consumer class where we are consuming messages from Kafka producer. We wanted to customize our Kafka stream by providing customized class in DefaultValueSerDes, which is not working and giving me error.

THIS IS MY PROGRAM.CS FILE

```
 // Stream configuration
var config = new StreamConfig();

config.ApplicationId = "app-testing";
config.BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
config.DefaultKeySerDes = new StringSerDes();
config.DefaultValueSerDes = new ABC();

StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder();

IKStream<string, ABC> str = builder.Stream<string, ABC>("test-input");
str.Filter((k, v) => v.Data >= 25 && v.Data <= 50).To("test-output");

Topology t = builder.Build();

// Create a stream instance with topology and configuration
KafkaStream stream = new KafkaStream(t, config);

// Subscribe CTRL + C to quit stream application
Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) =>
{
    stream.Dispose();
};

// Start stream instance with cancellable token
await stream.StartAsync();
```

THIS IS MY PROVIDED JSON IN KAFKA PRODUCER:

{"Name": "DND", "Data": 37}

THIS IS MY CUSTOMIZED CLASS ABC.CS

```
    public class ABC : ISerDes
    {
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Data { get; set; }

public object DeserializeObject(byte[] data, SerializationContext context)
{
    var bytesAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ABC>(bytesAsString);
}

public void Initialize(SerDesContext context)
{
    context.Config.BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
    context.Config.ApplicationId = "app-testing";
}

public byte[] SerializeObject(object data, SerializationContext context)
{
    var a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a);
}
}
```

This is the error we are receiving in Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console

> fail: Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.SourceProcessor[0]
> stream-task[0|0]|processor[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]- Impossible to receive source data because keySerdes and/or valueSerdes
> is not setted ! KeySerdes : StringSerDes | ValueSerdes : NULL fail:
> Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.Internal.TaskManager[0]
> Failed to process stream task 0-0 due to the following error:
> Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Errors.StreamsException: stream-task[0|0]|processor[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]- The value
> serdes is not compatible to the actual value for this processor.
> Change the default value serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct
> Serdes via method parameters(using the DSL)
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.AbstractProcessor`2.Process(ConsumeResult`2
> record)
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Crosscutting.ActionHelper.MeasureLatency(Action
> action)
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.StreamTask.Process()
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.Internal.TaskManager.Process(Int64 now)
> fail: Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.StreamThread[0]
> stream-thread[app-testing-6991f443-2473-4c72-9e6f-b1e596edc74b-stream-thread-0]
> Encountered the following error during processing:
> Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Errors.StreamsException: stream-task[0|0]|processor[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]- The value
> serdes is not compatible to the actual value for this processor.
> Change the default value serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct
> Serdes via method parameters(using the DSL)
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.AbstractProcessor`2.Process(ConsumeResult`2
> record)
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Crosscutting.ActionHelper.MeasureLatency(Action
> action)
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.StreamTask.Process()
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.Internal.TaskManager.Process(Int64 now)
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.StreamThread.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.b__3()
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Crosscutting.ActionHelper.MeasureLatency(Action
> action)
> at Streamiz.Kafka.Net.Processors.StreamThread.Run()

Comment: Your value serde wasn't set... `keySerdes and/or valueSerdes is not setted ! KeySerdes : StringSerDes | ValueSerdes : NULL`. You were given a response here https://github.com/LGouellec/kafka-streams-dotnet/issues/177#issuecomment-1259484038

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.